# Temperature rise in Ubuntu (with open source drivers)

Tags: 13.10, temperature, ivybridge

My laptop is a Dell 3520 with the following specifications.

Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4

Intel® Ivybridge Mobile Graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10. The temperature is 50 degrees when I boot the laptop. It rises to an average of 65-68 degrees very quickly. Running chrome and vlc (with normal videos) together takes the temperature to 75 degrees (on an average). Running 1080p videos makes the temperature shoot upto 85 degrees before shutting down.

Also I dont hear any fan sound. I doubt if it is running at all.

I tried searching for solutions and most of the problems are for NVIDIA graphics. I dont know what the problem is with my laptop. Could someone please help me solve this problem.

P.S: Please let me know if any more specification or system information is needed.

Comment: Does the fan actually work? Are you using any additional graphics to the integrated ones?

Comment: The fan works. I know this because I can hear the fan sound when in Windows. I have not installed any graphics on my own other than the ones that get installed along with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem on both my VAIO CR31 and ThinkPad since I installed Ubuntu a while ago. I'm afraid I don't have a neat solution that fixes the problem at its root but I can tell you what I did to circumvent the computer from heating up so much that it shuts down automatically.
Obviously, you can use an extra fan, that's what I do sometimes, but it's a bit sad at the same time. I came from Windows and still have them set up as dual boot. What works for me is to start Windows and fo to the Settings for "Power and Energy" or what it's called. I tuned it down from "high performance" to "medium". For some reason that I don't understand, it seems as if the system remembers this for all OSs. When I then start with Ubuntu, it's a bit slower of course but it's much cooler as well and doesn't shut down so easily. I reckon Ubuntu doesn't get the power management right and simply runs hyper-power all the time when Windows left the setting that way.
Hope it helps!